# Test order in has_many relationship with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm not very experienced with Rails and RSpec and often have troubles with writing tests. So, my next trouble is that I don't know how to test order in model's relationship properly.

Let's say I have simple model like this:

```
class Kitchen < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, -> { order(completed_at: :desc) }
end
```

And simple test for that model:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Kitchen, :type => :model do
  before { @kitchen = FactoryGirl.create(:kitchen) }

  subject { @kitchen }

  describe "orders" do
    before do
      @kitchen.orders.build(description: "Test description 1",
        completed_at: 1.day.ago.localtime)

      @kitchen.orders.build(description: "Test description 2",
        completed_at: Time.now)
    end

    it "should be sorted by completion date in descending order" do
      expect(@kitchen.orders.first.completed_at).to be > @kitchen.orders.last.completed_at
    end
  end
end
```

As a result I have got the error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(@kitchen.orders.first.completed_at).to be > @kitchen.orders.last.completed_at
   expected: > Fri, 15 May 2015 12:21:54 UTC +00:00
        got:   Thu, 14 May 2015 12:21:54 UTC +00:00
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `build`. This does not persist to the database, so when you call `@kitchen.orders.first`, you are not hitting the database, just getting back the first one you created, which is the wrong one.

Use `create` instead, then call `@kitchen.reload` to refresh from the database.

Comment: I was thinking this, but there must be some orders on `@kitchen` otherwise the expect line would error.

Comment: @DickieBoy When I've used `build` before like this, it leaves the built objects attached to the parent, so the expect line is getting them like that. Calls to the DB are cached, which is why the `reload` method exists, so the built objects are treated as if they were the result of a previous DB call.

Comment: Ah i see what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

How about the following:

```
it {
    is_expected.to have_many(:orders).order( completed_at: :desc )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
RSpec.describe Kitchen, :type => :model do
  let(:kitchen) { FactoryGirl.create(:kitchen) }

  describe 'orders' do
    let(:yesterday) { 1.day.ago }
    let(:today)     { Time.now }

    before do
      # `create` actually saves the objects into the database
      kitchen.orders.create(description: '1', completed_at: today)
      kitchen.orders.create(description: '2', completed_at: yesterday)
    end

    # `(true)` forces a reload of the associated objects
    subject(:orders) { kitchen.orders(true) } 

    it 'should be sorted by completion date in descending order' do
      expect(orders.map(&:completed_at)).to eq [yesterday, today]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have tried to create orders with FactoryGirl and it seems like not necessary to reload model as suggested in Matt Gibson's answer or call `orders(true)`. Test completed successfully regardless of what order was created first.

Comment: Yes, thank you again. The example of RSpec test suggested by you is very helpful for me but I am going to accept Matt Gibson's answer as he provided the description of my issue in it and his answer is also correct.